# Java stream get single element from collection

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using a non stream way to get single element from collection.

```
List<MyCustomClass> list = OtherObject.getMyList();

if (list.size() != 1) {
throw new RuntimeException();
}

MyCustomClass customClass = list.get(0);
```

Instead of this multi liner approach, is there some way to achieve this via streams?

Comment: There's a way to get the first element, but there's no built-in way to assert that a stream has _exactly_ one item; this isn't part of the use pattern of streams.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- That is [incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151443/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas That isn't a built-in way to do it, and it is horrible in every imaginable way.

Comment: @Polygnome I never said it was pretty, but it is a way to achieve what OP wants, using streams. And it is built-in, the only custom code is the construction of the exceptions to throw. Or would you also say that sorting isn't built-in because it requires the user to supply the comparison (natural or explicit)? I'd disagree with that strict interpretation of "built-in".

Comment: @Andreas by your usage of built-in, everything you can possibly write in java is "built-in". need a CNN? Here is just some lines of code, this is all built in in Java... yeah no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce(accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and [`orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) to ensure the stream produces exactly one result.

```
MyCustomClass customClass = list.stream()
        .reduce((a,b) -> { throw new RuntimeException("Too many values present"); })
        .orElseThrow(() -> { throw new RuntimeException("No value present"); });
```

Comment: This isn't built in, it's much less clear than the OP's original code, and it's much less efficient.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- `reduce()` and `orElseThrow()` are both built-in. OP didn't ask for cleaner/simpler code, only for a stream solution to do the same in a single statement ("one-liner").

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning an optional from `findFirst()` or `findAny()`.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

Optional<String> maybeFirst = strings.stream().findFirst();
// we now have an optional, lets force a value

String value = maybeFirst.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
// if there isn't a value, we'll throw an illegal argument exception.
```

This can collapsed into the following.

```
String value = strings.stream()
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("There must be at least one string."));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Edited to remove such claim.

Comment: This answer does not handle the case when the list has more than one element.

Comment: That's fair. From the original question it seemed as though the check for exactly one element was just a way to ensure there would be _some_ element to grab. Thats where using ```findAny``` or ```findFirst``` would come in handy.

Comment: But in the question, the condition to check is `list.size() != 1` instead of `list.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a version with a single collect statement, although it turned out not as concise or elegant as the solution by Andreas. It uses an implementation of `Collector` that accumulates to a one-element list, while the combiner raises an exception if we have more than one element; the finisher raises an exception when the list is empty.

```
list.stream().collect(
    Collector.of( ArrayList::new, 
                  (a, t) -> { if (!a.isEmpty())
                                  throw new RuntimeException();
                              a.add(t); },
                  (a, b) -> { throw new RuntimeException(); },
                  a -> { if( a.isEmpty() )
                             throw new RuntimeException();
                         return a.get(0);} );
```